# Passing a knockout array of objects to an mvc controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, viewmodel

Folks,
Can anyone help me or direct me to an example of a knockout viewmodel which contains an array of objects being passed to an asp.net mvc action? The only examples I have seen show just simple arrays of strings being passed.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does your data look like, controller action, ko view model? Please post some code.

Comment: What have you tried. Perhaps you can give us some of your code to work with so we don't have to try and read your mind

Comment: Do you know about [Knockout MVC ?](http://knockoutmvc.com/)

Comment: Guys we are still in the mock-up phase. We do not have our model yet,  I am looking ahead at spikes and trying to prepare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's an example from the official Knockout site](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html). It's a Contacts editor build with nested arrays. [[jsFiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gZC5k/).

A fitting ASP.NET MVC Action could look like

```
public ActionResult SaveContacts(IEnumerable<Contact> contacts)
```

Where Contact is defined as the class:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Number> phones { get; set; }
}
```

Where Number is defined as the class:

```
public class Number
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

Given the JavaScript Knockout View Model from the [example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html). Your `save` method could look like this

```
self.save = function() {
    var jsonString = ko.mapping.toJSON(this.searchParams);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/MyController/SaveContacts",
        data: jsonString,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you Martin. Can you show me what the SaveContacts posting method in the knockout viewmodel would look like?

Comment: Sure. I've added a save method to my answer as a replacement for the save method from the example. Make sure you take a look at this example -> http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html